# How to access a class variable inside a HostListener event handler

Tags: angular

I'm trying to check which event listener to set by checking `'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click'`, and then I want to add this inside a `@HostListener` but I'm unable to do this because `this` is not available in the `document:click` section.

Can you achieve this somehow?

```js
constructor(private _globals: GlobalVariablesService, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  this.ns = _globals.ns;
  this.deviceListener = ('ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click');
}

// How can I add the this.deviceListener instead of click?
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onOutsideClick(e) {
  const nativeElement = this._elementRef.nativeElement;

  // If the clicked element is not the component element or any of its children, close the dropdown
  if (nativeElement !== e.target && !nativeElement .contains(e.target)) {
    this.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2.  Basically, add it imperatively inside your constructor.

Comment: @MarkRajcok After an answer to a question I posted yesterday I was under the impression that you shouldn't add event listeners like that.

Comment: What class variable do you try to access? What's the problem with accessing `deviceListener`? `this.deviceListener` should just work in `onOutsideClick() { ... }`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I can access the variable inside onOutsideClick without a problem, but that's not where I tell angular which events to listen for. That's done in the `@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])` part, and instead of writing `document:click` I would like to write `this.deviceListener`. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: I think I got it now. I guess this doesn't work with `@HostListener()` Use `Renderer` like in the answer linked above by @MarkRajcok instead if you need this.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I think he wants to write this, but can't: `@HostListener('document:' + this.deviceListener, ...)`.  However, this seems to work okay: `@HostListener('document:' + ('ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click'), ...)`

Comment: Chrillewoodz, regarding the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376442/where-does-dom-manipulation-belong-in-angular-2) you posted yesterday... shouldn't add event listeners using `window.addEventListener()`.  Using Renderer is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```ts
@HostListener('document:' + ('ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchend' : 'click'), ...)
```

or add it imperatively inside your constructor, as shown in this question: [Dynamically add event listener in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2):

```ts
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
   if('ontouchstart' in window) {
       this.listenFn = renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'ontouchstart', (event) => {
           // do something with 'event'
       });
   } else {
       this.listenFn = renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
           // do something with 'event'
       });
   }
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.listenFn();  // removes the listener
}
```

If you add it imperatively, be sure to remove it imperatively.

Comment: What is the purpose of using renderer instead of just binding directly then?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, if you need more complex binding logic, use Renderer.  For your specific scenario, HostListener is fine.