# How to trigger an event when component is navigated to?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an angular2 application (RC5), where I have a **chapter** component. This basically has a big template file - **chapter.html** - which has this:

```
<div *ngIf="chapter == 1">
<!-- Chapter 1 content -->
</div>
<div *ngIf="chapter == 2">
<!-- Chapter 2 content -->
</div>
<!-- etc. -->
```

I then have some arrow buttons for *next* and for *previous* chapters. These trigger an event e.g.

```
if (this.chapter !== '6') {
  var next = parseInt(this.chapter) + 1;
  console.log(next);
  let link = ['/tutorial/chapter', next];
  this.router.navigate(link);
}
```

So that all works fine, however, the buttons are at the bottom of a chapter, so when they are clicked, the next chapter is displayed, but automatically scrolled down. So on the router click, I would like to trigger an event and scroll to the top of the page, however, as I am navigating to the same component, `ngOnInit()` isn't triggered.

How can I do this?

Comment: `window.scrollTop=0;` Scroll back up?

Comment: @epascarello yes exactly, but I want an event to execute that from, which is triggered after the component is navigated too

Comment: So listen for when the chapter is updated or router.subscribe?

Comment: old question but i think now you can configure the root routing module with `scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to the same component, at least a parameter has changed, otherwise the router wouldn't re-navigate.

You can subscribe to parameter changes and invoke scrolling on changes

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.params.forEach(p => this.doScroll());
}
```

Comment: Also, How would you recommend scrolling to the top of a vertically overflowing div? Maybe as in your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376442/where-does-dom-manipulation-belong-in-angular-2) here?

Comment: Can't you just set scrollTop to 0?

Comment: as in `window.scrollTop=0;`?

Comment: I thinks so. I don't know it by heart and I'm currently only on the phone.

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        //do your stuffs...
  });
}
```