# Angular 2+ Multi Clients Multi Stylesheets

Tags: css, angular

I have a situation where I will have different styles based on different clients/users.

These will all be running from the same site so I will have to load in the style dynamically once I determine which client has logged in.

What is the recommended way of doing this in Angular 2? i.e. I don't want to use jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Would some solution with `[ngStyle]` do?

Comment: no there will be too many styles and they may change

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<head>
   <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="red.css">
</head>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({})
export class MyClass {
    constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      //here you can check for the users and then chnage depending upon the user
      this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', 'blue.css');
    }
}
```

Comment: is direct dom manipulation from a component not recommended? (may not possible to avoid i guess?)

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation should be avoided entirely in Angular2. use bindings instead  ref - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376442/where-does-dom-manipulation-belong-in-angular-2

Comment: strange that you should give me a direct dom manipulation answer no? changed your mind fairly quickly :)

Comment: its should be avoided and if you are playing with it you should be cautious , and you cannot get hold of entire style sheets in  bindings rather you can get hold of properties, if you want to change property wise that too is possible but a fairly long code base for the same