# How to get next Element/siblings in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am a newbie on Angular2, I have to get the next element value/text in Angular2 but I am not able to do so. It is very easy in Jquery but I didnt find any way to achieve the same in Angular2. Please help.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="div1">Here is Div-1 content</div>
<div id="div2">Here is Div-2 content</div>
```

In jquery it is very easy to do like:

```
$('#div1').next().text();
```

How the same can be done in **Angular 2**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does DOM manipulation belong in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376442/where-does-dom-manipulation-belong-in-angular-2)

Comment: no, it is not. My question is something different.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is not angular specific thing, but at least in javascript you can do this: `document.getElementById('div1').nextSibling` where you can find the properties of said element. And you can increment index to find next siblings after or check for children, so on and so forth.

[You can read about implementation here on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use element reference and use that same way you do in jQuery.

Inject the element reference to your component

```
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

  }
```

Then use query selector

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.div1').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: yes this can give me what I want but I m wandering for any other way. Is there any other way?

Comment: @ViewChild is also there but not sure and not tried. you can look into that too. You can also bind some component variable to the tag as well. i think there are other ways as well.